# Loopback $owner only

Tags: strongloop, loopback

I have an loopback app where each customer can have it's own services. Therefore I would need customer to be able only to see, add, edit and delete only it's own services. But no matter what I do, it seems that the customer can either see all services from all users, or no one can see no one's service.

The service model

```
"relations": {
  "customer": {
    "type": "belongsTo",
    "model": "customer",
    "foreignKey": "customerId"
  }
}
```

And the alc as I've see it:

```
"acls": [
  {
    "accessType": "*",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "DENY"
  },
  {
    "accessType": "*",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$owner",
    "permission": "ALLOW"
  }
]
```

But if it's like this owner of the service and only /GET/{id} it's service, but it cannot /GET all services?!?

If I use this:

```
"acls": [
  {
    "accessType": "*",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$everyone",
    "permission": "DENY"
  },
  {
    "accessType": "*",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$authenticated",
    "permission": "ALLOW"
  }
]
```

I've got what I need but this is a mayor security leak since each customer can get ALL services from all other customers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add property `customerId` in your `service` model and the `$owner` acl works only if the `:id` segment exists in the api url.

If your urls does not have any `:id` you can create your custom role resolver.

Comment: I've wrote that I got it covered with GET on /{id} (/:id), and I know that. But what about if I don't want single service using id, but all services that are of that $owner?

Comment: @Arcagully As I mentioned in my answer, you need `customerId` property and if you want to cover all services ignoring id segment, so creating custom role resolver is the way

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, while expanding my API from the user model. As the answer suggests I've passed through the userId but still all users would be able to access the data. Can you please help me with this?